# Using values of dictionary passed to a Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a test code I want to use to ask the question:

```
dct = {}
dct ['a'] = 1
dct ['b'] = 2
dct ['c'] = 'test'
def myfunc(p,dct):
    c = dct['c']
    print ('a')
    print (dct['b']) 
    print (c)

myfunc('p',dct)
```

The output is:

```
a
2
test
```

my real function needs 7-8 parameters, which I decided to pack into a dictionary. Is there a way that I can use those parameters by calling them by their names (`a`,`b`,`c`) instead of `dct['b']` or by explicitly creating a variable matching a key (such as `c=dct['c']`). Also, I am not sure why `print ('a')` returns `a`. I was expecting an error or, in an ideal world, the real value as `1`.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `print ('a')` is just printing the string `"a"`.

Comment: Why would `print('a')` not return `'a'`, you pass it a string, so Python prints that. It does not have to be a dictionary, etc.

Comment: You can pass a dict as keyword arguments of the type `key=value` with `myfunc(**dct)`

Comment: Read about keyword arguments in Python (for example [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/)). You can declare all the parameters in your function (`def myfunc(p, a, b, c):`) and then call it like `myfunc('p', **dct)`

Comment: Please work through more language tutorials.  You seem to be confused about the differences among a scalar variable and basic data aggregates (dict, list, string, etc.).

Comment: Furthermore using a variable without properly defining it, is quite unsafe. It is better to declare the functions in the head. Strictly speaking it is possible to unpack a dictionary in local variables. But that would be a serious anti-pattern. Especially since it can "hide" other variables like `list`, `dict`, etc. that you want to use *inside* the function.